# Edit .RAR file comments from python

Tags: python, windows, archive, python-2.6

Ok, I need to be able to *edit* the file comments in .rar files from python.

I can already view the comments using [UnRAR](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyUnRAR/1.0). However, I need to embed metadata in the files in a way that is preserved over multiple file systems (e.g. alternate datastreams are out), so I can't really think of any other alternatives.

[rarfile](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/rarfile/) *seems* like it might work, but it doesn't really function correctly under windows, despite it's claim of platform independence (or the .rar format has changed, but that seems unlikely considering other utilities from the same time period work). It opens the archive fine, but it does not recognize that there are comments.

To pre-emptively answer some of the inevitable comments -
No, I cannot convert the archives (there's thousands of them).
Any file-system-dependent mode of storing metadata is out, as I need to support NTFS, XFS and ext3.
Hidden files would be a mess, and you need to ensure they are moved with the associated file, which I cannot do.

Comment: Alternatively, does anyone know any good sources of internal documentation on the rar format? That way, I can start hacking at rarfile, and maybe figure out why it's barfing on my .rar files.
(I've seen http://kthoom.googlecode.com/hg/docs/unrar.html)

Comment: Isn't editing something in the archive likely to mean extracting and re-compressing it anyway? (unless the rar format is much cleverer than I would give it credit for...)

In which case, I don't see why converting to a more friendly archive type is out of the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm hoping to avoid.
From what I can tell of the .rar architecture, the comment is separately compressed, so it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck. Unfortunately the RAR format is closed source and not documented, and there is no Python module that does what you want to do.

The only open-source tool I know that uncompress RAR files is The Unarchiver. I think that your best bet is check their [sources](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cptnLveUsMI/trunk/XADMaster/unrar/rarvm.cpp&q=rar%20package:http://theunarchiver%5C.googlecode%5C.com&d=3) and write your own Python tool to change the file comments.

You might also try to ask this question at the [comp.compression](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.compression/topics?pli=1) boards, I had a similar [issue](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.compression/browse_thread/thread/40c28989c4d02a5/7afcd6ebae3c004a?lnk=gst&q=canassa#7afcd6ebae3c004a) some years ago with an obscure compression format and the people over there were able to help me in no time.